# HttpPlatformHandler for Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Is there something like IIS [HttpPlatformHandler](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler) for Apache 2 server in reverse proxy role?

I am specially interested in process management of HTTP listeners, to let Apache start the process if it is not running yet and stop it when it is not used for some time.

Comment: There are Apache modules such as [`mod_fcgid`](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/), which use the FastCGI interface to communicate with listening processes (which can then run the language of their choice for processing the CGI data).  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: No, I meant something what can also start the listener process if it is not running yet.